# How do I reposition an artboard which is covered by an image?

Tags: artboard, adobe-xd

If I have an artboard with an image covering the whole background, how can I move it around? There is nowhere to grab the board and cmd click to move it as usual. If I try to move it, I just end up dragging the image off the artboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest locking the image and move the artboard as you need.
Select the image then go to the menu as show in the pic.
To unlock afterwards just to to the same menu for unlock and all locked objects will be released.

Keyboard shortcut to lock is Cmd+2 (for mac) or Ctrl+2 (for pc).

To release is Cmd+Alt+2 (for mac) or Ctrl+Alt+2 (for pc).

[image: 1]]

Comment: This is not a XD screenshot and not XD shortcuts. Cmd+2 zooms in.

Comment: Yes, shortcuts may vary from machine to machine. The ones I wrote are the ones I had by default. Being default I assumed most users get the same ones as I did Anyway you get the same result by using the menus as shown.
What do you mean by "this is not a screenshot" @Hexodus

Comment: This does not work in the 2020 version. If you lock the images you still cannot move the artboard through them. The best solution I found is essentially to change the arboard width with some extra 'handle space. It's a hack but someone there has been no reasonable solutions from the devs.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the artboard title as a handle. Click the artboard title, then you can drag it wherever you'd like.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it always works.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and, it also makes me sad

Answer (score 0):

This, unfortunately is more of  hack, bu there has yet to be a resonable solution from the devs: change the arboard width to include some extra 'handle' space; change the background of the artboard itself to something bright enough to see. If you need the arboard to have a particular background, crate a locked layer and fill it with that color.

[image]